# ANTLR4 dynamic rule element labels access

Tags: c#, dynamic, label, antlr4, rule

I am new to Antr. I recently discovered that there is the option for creating rule element labels dynamically like this:

```
variable 
    :   mainField = variableName ( '.' subFields += variableName )*                   
    ;
```

I am using c sharp. I can use `context.mainField` in my code without any problems but I cannot find our how can I access the subFields list. Only a `_subFields` Interface type shows up in intellisense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_subFields` is in fact the `List` that I was looking for. I was confused.